# Identity IQ does not start

Tags: java

Currently, I am using a virtual machine in Oracle cloud. I have successfully installed Tomcat and IdentityIQ. The server is deployed correctly, but when I try to access through Google Chrome with the credentials, I get the following error.

[image: Error message]

I have disabled the firewall and when I try to test the connection with ping it does not respond.

Comment: I am not familiar with IdentityIQ, what do you want to expose to the internet, whatever runs into tomcat? What do you use to expose your application?

Comment: I want to expose the IdentityIQ application. I'm going to expose it through Tomcat. I want to access it through the chrome browser. The server correctly displays the IdentityIQ application but when I try to access through the Chrome browser through the IP address of the device and its port I get the error that I have attached in the image.

Comment: Have you installed and configured nginx or another reverse proxy program to handle the connections to the application?

Comment: Yes, who manages the server is tomcat. Tomcat deploys the server and maintains it.

Comment: How do you expose tomcat to the internet from the server?